# c# convert class to query string

Tags: c#

Im trying to convert a few classes/objects in my application to a query string for example:

```
public class LoginRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public otherclass d { get; set; }
}

public class otherclass
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

would then become:

```
username=test&password=p&a=123&b=123
```

Which i am achieving with the following function

```
private string ObjectToQueryString<T>(T obj) where T: class {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Type t = obj.GetType();

    var properties = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        if (p.CanRead)
        {
            var indexes = p.GetIndexParameters();
            if (indexes.Count() > 0)
            {
                var pp = p.GetValue(obj, new object[] { 1 });
                sb.Append(ObjectToQueryString(pp));
            }
            else
            {

                //I dont think this is a good way to do it
                if (p.PropertyType.FullName != p.GetValue(obj, null).ToString())
                {
                    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", p.Name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.GetValue(obj, null).ToString())));
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(ObjectToQueryString(p.GetValue(obj, null)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd('&');
}
```

but If I pass a list into the function it will also include the Count and Capacity properties and other thing I dont want. Say its a list of

```
List<otherclass>()
```

Cheers

Comment: This is probably best sent properly serialized (as XML for example) over POST, instead of as part of the querystring.

Comment: Sorry should have added. The string is then hashed and used as a hash in the header

Comment: Would also suggest object to string serialisation, but JSON. Json.Net is a safe start. Then url-encode the json and append it. like your gravatar ;-)

Comment: Just a side issue, but you do know that passing passwords through query strings is really bad, right? I mean, we're talking Star Wars Episode I bad.

Comment: I'm not passing passwords on clear text over query string. I don't want the world to explode. It was just an example class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty simple to me, check if the class is an IEnumerable or IEnumerator and if so Enumerate it (rather than reflecting that particular class).  It would help if you explained how you'd like us to deal with such results.

```
//username=bob&password=123&a=Cheese&b=Chocolate&a=Cat&b=Dog

public class LoginRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public List<OtherClass> d { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var request = new LoginRequest
    {
        username = "bob",
        password = "123",
        d = new List<OtherClass> { new OtherClass { a = "Cheese", b = "Chocolate" } ,
        new OtherClass { a = "Cat", b = "Dog" } }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(ObjectToQueryString(request));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string ObjectToQueryString<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable data = obj as IEnumerable ?? new[] { obj };

    foreach (var datum in data)
    {
        Type t = datum.GetType();
        var properties = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
        {
            if (p.CanRead)
            {
                var indexes = p.GetIndexParameters();
                if (indexes.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var pp = p.GetValue(datum, new object[] { 1 });
                    sb.Append(ObjectToQueryString(pp));
                }
                else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType  != typeof(string))
                {
                    sb.Append(ObjectToQueryString(p.GetValue(datum)));
                }
                else
                {

                    //I dont think this is a good way to do it
                    if (p.PropertyType.FullName != p.GetValue(datum, null).ToString())
                    {
                        //sb.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", p.Name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.GetValue(datum, null).ToString())));
                        sb.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", p.Name, p.GetValue(datum, null).ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(ObjectToQueryString(p.GetValue(datum, null)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd('&');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the point, why you are trying it complicated like that?

```
public class LoginRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public otherclass d { get; set; }

    public String getQueryString(){
      return "username="+this.username+"&password="+this.password+"&a="+this.d.a+"&b="+this.d.b;
    }
}

public class otherclass
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

... or did you miss something in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the BindingFlags argument of GetProperties()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | ...)
```

to limit its result to properties declared by your type.